# Pandas: split row into multiple rows based on value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like:

```
Name EID Schedule
A    001 Mo-We 6a-6a 
B    002 Mo-We 6a-1a
C    003 M&TUE&W&THU 6A-1A
```

I would like the data to end up looking like

```
Name EID DOW StartHour EndHour
A    001 Monday 6      6
A    001 Tuesday 6     6
A    001 Wednesday 6   6
B    002 Monday 6      1
B    002 Tuesday 6     1
B    002 Wednesday 6   1
C    003 Monday    6   1
C    003 Tuesday 6     1
C    003 Wednesday 6   1
C    003 Thursday  6   1
```

I am fairly new to pandas and have light python experience and am kind of stuck on how to go forward with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a Person class for each Name and feed into it the raw data you have. You will have to write functions that do the operations: "Mo-We" -> ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"], "M&TUE" -> ["Monday", "Tuesday"] and "6a-6a" -> (6, 6).

I haven't written those parsing functions, but I can help with that if you're stuck on that too. Here's the structure to get you started:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, eid, raw_days, raw_timings):
        self.name = name
        self.eid = int(eid)
        self.days = parse_days(raw_days)  # ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]
        self.start_hour, self.end_hour = parse_timings(raw_timings)  # (int, int)

    def to_dicts(self):
        dicts = []
        for day in self.days:
            dicts.append({"Name": self.name, "EID": self.eid, "DOW": day, "StartHour": self.start_hour, "EndHour": self.end_hour})

        return dicts


def parse_days(raw_days):
    return []


def parse_timings(raw_timings):
    return None, None
```

Once you parse all your input data and have a list of Person objects, you can call person.to_dicts() on each person and append that to the DataFrame:

```
for person in persons:
    df.append(person.to_dicts())
```

Comment: Help on the parsing function would definitely be welcome.